# Why is InterLocked is slower than lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Just for curiosity I made a program to test the performance of InterLocked vs lock in .Net.
It turns out InterLocked version is far slower than Locked version, can someone please point out if I am missing some details here.
As per my understanding Interlocked should perform much better than lock.

```
public class TestB
    {
        private static readonly object _objLocker = new object();
        private long _shared;
        public void IncrLocked()
        {
            lock (_objLocker)
            {
                _shared++;
            }
        }
        public void IncrInterLocked()
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _shared);
        }
        public long GetValue()
        {
            return _shared;
        }
    }
    class TestsCopy
    {
        private static TestB _testB = new TestB();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numofthreads = 100;
            TestInterLocked(numofthreads);
            TestLocked(numofthreads);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void TestInterLocked(int numofthreads)
        {
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[numofthreads];
            for (int i = 0; i < numofthreads; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(StartTestInterLocked);
                threads[i] = t;
                t.Start();
            }
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
            {
                threads[i].Join();
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Interlocked finished in : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}, value = {_testB.GetValue()}");
        }

        private static void TestLocked(int numofthreads)
        {
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[numofthreads];
            for (int i = 0; i < numofthreads; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(StartTestLocked);
                threads[i] = t;
                t.Start();
            }
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
            {
                threads[i].Join();
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Locked finished in : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}, value = {_testB.GetValue()}");
        }

        private static void StartTestInterLocked()
        {
            int counter = 10000000;
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                _testB.IncrInterLocked();
            }
        }
        private static void StartTestLocked()
        {
            int counter = 10000000;
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                _testB.IncrLocked();
            }
        }
```

The output of the program is ...

```
Interlocked finished in : 76909 ms, value = 1000000000
Locked finished in : 44215 ms, value = 2000000000
```

Comment: You're only testing the case where there is an extreme lot of concurrent access here. For a fairer test, you should also test which is faster when there is no concurrent access, or a normal amount.

Comment: I think your measurement is flawed. You start all the threads before you start the StopWatch. Many, if not most, of the threads will have completed before the measurement starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test is flawed for the reason mentioned by Jakob Olsen. Additionally, your test is also including the overhead of calling methods in a class (for the `lock`, obviously that can't be avoided for calling `Interlocked.Increment()`.

You should start all the threads and arrange for them to start working after you've started the stopwatch. You can do that by making them wait on a `ManualResetEvent`.

I've rewritten your test code like so:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static readonly object _objLocker = new object();
        private static long _shared;
        private static ManualResetEvent _signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numofthreads = 100;
            TestInterLocked(numofthreads);
            TestLocked(numofthreads);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TestInterLocked(int numofthreads)
        {
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[numofthreads];
            for (int i = 0; i < numofthreads; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(StartTestInterLocked);
                threads[i] = t;
                t.Start();
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // Make sure threads have had time to start.
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            _shared = 0;
            _signal.Set();

            for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
            {
                threads[i].Join();
            }

            sw.Stop();
            _signal.Reset();
            Console.WriteLine($"Interlocked finished in : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}, value = {_shared}");
        }

        private static void TestLocked(int numofthreads)
        {
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[numofthreads];
            for (int i = 0; i < numofthreads; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(StartTestLocked);
                threads[i] = t;
                t.Start();
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // Make sure threads have had time to start.
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            _shared = 0;
            _signal.Set();

            for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
            {
                threads[i].Join();
            }

            sw.Stop();
            _signal.Reset();
            Console.WriteLine($"Locked finished in : {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}, value = {_shared}");
        }

        private static void StartTestInterLocked()
        {
            _signal.WaitOne();
            int counter = 10000000;
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _shared);
            }
        }

        private static void StartTestLocked()
        {
            _signal.WaitOne();
            int counter = 10000000;
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
            {
                lock (_objLocker)
                {
                    _shared++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the results are (from a RELEASE build):

```
Interlocked finished in : 11339, value = 1000000000
Locked finished in : 30546, value = 1000000000
```

As you can see, `Interlocked` is substantially faster.

Comment: on my machine the output is Interlocked finished in : 139614, value = 1000000000
Locked finished in : 30432, value = 1000000000

Comment: I am missing some optimization, why do i have Interlocked so slower on my machine ?

Comment: @Bovi_Khurja You are definitely running a release version outside the debugger? And do you have a 32 bit or a 64 bit operating system? Are you building the executable as x64/AnyCPU?

Comment: I am running outside debugger. 64 bit OS, exe with AnyCPU

Comment: @Bovi_Khurja Very strange. I cannot reproduce what you're seeing. What happens if you use an `int` instead of a `long`?

Comment: with int output is: Interlocked finished in : 21365, value = 1000000000
Locked finished in : 27231, value = 1000000000

Comment: @Bovi_Khurja It does sound like a 32bit/64bit thing then. Not sure how, though. You haven't got "Prefer 32-bit" ticked in the Build options, have you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111514/discussion-between-bovi-khurja-and-matthew-watson).

Comment: found something, I had "Prefer 32-bit" checked, after removing that Interlocked is faster but very slightly, no dramatically better.