# How to execute code when the second method completes

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a situation where I need to execute some code at the end of 1 of 2 methods - whichever completes second. My particular case is Blazor server where I need to execute this code at the end of  OnInitializedAsync()/ OnAfterRenderAsync(). In this case the code depends on JavaScript being callable and the page model being fully populated from the database.

I have come up with the following class to accomplish this:

```
public class DoubleFinish
{
    private volatile bool _firstFinished = false;
    private volatile bool _secondFinished = false;
    private volatile bool _alreadyReturnedTrue = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Call when the first method completes. Returns true if the 2nd method is also
    /// complete and so this method can now run the code that requires both methods.
    /// </summary>
    public bool TryFirstFinished
    {
        get
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                _firstFinished = true;
                if (_alreadyReturnedTrue || ! _secondFinished)
                    return false;
                _alreadyReturnedTrue = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call when the second method completes. Returns true if the 1st method is also
    /// complete and so this method can now run the code that requires both methods.
    /// </summary>
    public bool TrySecondFinished
    {
        get
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                _secondFinished = true;
                if (_alreadyReturnedTrue || ! _firstFinished)
                    return false;
                _alreadyReturnedTrue = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then in my razor.cs file have the following (the two methods these are in can be in different tasks and therefore be executing at the same time):

```
OnInitializedAsync() {
    // ... lots of DB access
    if (DoubleFinish.TryFirstFinished)
        await OnAfterInitializeAndRenderAsync();
}

OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
    if (!firstRender)
        return;
    if (DoubleFinish.TrySecondFinished)
        await OnAfterInitializeAndRenderAsync();
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Do I need to declare the bools in `DoubleFinish` `volatile`?
2. Is there some kind of atomic call to check/set the bool values that avoids the use of `lock`?

**Update:** One major constraint. `OnInitializedAsync()` can be called  twice in some configurations. So I can't use a counter. I have to track specifically that each method has completed.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Do you have a full [mre]?

Comment: The bools are not `volatile`. "Is there some kind of atomic call to check/set the bool values ...?" See the [Interlocked Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=net-7.0). From [lock Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) you want to avoid `lock (this)`.

Comment: @JonathanDodds First off, thank you for the don't use 'lock(this)` - I was not aware of that. On the Interlocked class, I didn't see a way to work with the 3 bools with that. I have a constraint that `OnInitializedAsync()` can be called twice so I can't use a counter. thanks

Comment: @JonathanDodds What do you mean by the bools are not volatile?

Comment: @GuruStron A "minimal" example is not that simple because it requires a Blazor server app. But then in that app put the code I showed above as the last code in OnInitializedAsync/OnAfterRenderAsync methods and that's the MRE.

Comment: *"`OnInitializedAsync()` can be called twice in some configurations."* -- What should happen in this scenario? Should the DB queries run again on the second call? Is it possible that the two `OnInitializedAsync` calls are concurrent?

Comment: The `volatile` keyword is used to indicate that multiple threads could change the field at the same time. The bools are private and only used within the critical section. You are using the same lock object for both critical sections.

Comment: Have you considered using a set of [`EventWaitHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/eventwaithandle)s with manual resets?

Comment: @JonathanDodds yes but isn't that more expensive than a lock?

Comment: As noted in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77457212/60761) the Blazor lifecycle is (quasi) single-threaded so none of this is necessary. And it does run the risk of deadlocking.

Comment: @HH I disagree with you on half of what you said. If the lifecycle is single-threaded, then deadlocking is impossible as deadlocking occurs between conflicting threads.

Comment: You're right, this code won't deadlock. But it's still a risky thing to do on the UI thread, sooner or later somebody will use InvokeAsync() in this path. And it's still not necessary to `lock {}` here.

Comment: @HH I'm sorry, I still don't see the risk? You're right that the lock is arguably not necessary. But I don't see how there's any risk from having the lock. If both did not execute on the UI thread and they were truly executing at the same time, one would block until the other completed and then execute. No race condition, no deadlock possibility. What am I not seeing?

Comment: @HH I don't see the deadlock risk either. The two property getters don't call each other and, if they did, the two critical sections use the same lock object. A thread entering one of the critical sections locks both critical sections.

Comment: @DavidThielen Yes, `EventWaitHandle` is more 'expensive' than `lock`.  The conversation has moved on considerably since my comment and you have determined that "the `lock` is not necessary". But as general advice, 'expensive' is relative because code that is fast and unreliable is not helpful.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I found the discussion on this question to be very educational. It's funny how some "small" questions end up being very educational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I recommend reading the other answers and the comments. There's a lot of subtlety to this and the discussion walks through all of that. Well worth the time.

Second, for my particular use case the lock is not necessary. While both `OnInitializeAsync()` and `OnAfterRenderAsync()`, they both execute in the same UI thread. So they cannot be calling the `Try` methods simultaneously.

Third, if you do need this functionality where the calls can come from different threads, use my `lock` approach. The other approaches that use `Interlocked` make safe individual calls. But 2 or 3 `Interlocked` calls in a row are not a single atomic action. They are 2 or 3 discrete atomic actions. And for this use case, you need all those operations as a single atomic action.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be simpler to use the [`Interlocked.Decrement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.decrement) method, and decrease atomically an integer counter. When the counter goes down to zero, you can be sure that the last pending operation has completed:

```
private int _pendingCount = 2;

OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // ...
    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref _pendingCount) == 0)
        await OnAfterInitializeAndRenderAsync();
}

OnAfterRenderAsync()
{
    // ...
    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref _pendingCount) == 0)
        await OnAfterInitializeAndRenderAsync();
}
```

---

**Updated:** In case each of the two methods can be called more than once, it becomes more complex but you can still use the [`Interlocked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked) class. Here is an implementation of the atomic [bitwise OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-or-operator-) operation for the `uint` type:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the result of an atomic bitwise OR operation.
/// </summary>
static uint AtomicBitwiseOr(ref uint location, uint operand)
{
    uint oldValue = location;
    while (true)
    {
        uint newValue = oldValue | operand;
        uint original = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref location, newValue, oldValue);
        if (original == oldValue) return newValue;
        oldValue = original;
    }
}
```

It could be used like this:

```
private uint _state = 0;

OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // ...
    if (AtomicBitwiseOr(ref _state, 0b1) == 0b11)
        await OnAfterInitializeAndRenderAsync();
}

OnAfterRenderAsync()
{
    // ...
    if (AtomicBitwiseOr(ref _state, 0b10) == 0b11)
        await OnAfterInitializeAndRenderAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to use [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-7.0):

```
private int counter = 2;

OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // ...
    if (Interlocked.Increment(ref counter) == 2)
        YourCodeToRun();
}

OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    // ...
    if (Interlocked.Increment(ref counter) == 2)
        YourCodeToRun();
}
```

Or `SemaphoreSlim` or [`AsyncCountdownEvent`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncCountdownEvent.cs) from `Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination`. Something like the following (if it is feasible in Blazor context):

```
private AsyncCountdownEvent signal = new AsyncCountdownEvent(2);

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await signal.WaitAsync();
    YourCodeToRun();
})

OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // ...
    signal.Signal();
}

OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    // ...
    signal.Signal();
}
```

**UPD**

If `OnInitializedAsync` can run multiple times then your solution should be fine. Note that you should avoid using `lock(this)`, just create a `private object _locker = new object();` field for locking and volatile should not be needed since you are using the booleans only inside locks.

Or you can play with such monstrosity (though I would stick with locking):

```
private int flag1 = 0;
private int flag2 = 0;
private int hasRun = 0;

OnInitializedAsync()
{
    // ...
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref flag1, 1);
    if(Interlocked.Read(ref flag1) + Interlocked.Read(ref flag2) == 2 && Interlocked.Exchange(ref hasRun, 1) == 0)
        YourCodeToRun();
}

OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    // ...
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref flag2, 1);
    if(Interlocked.Read(ref flag1) + Interlocked.Read(ref flag2) == 2 && Interlocked.Exchange(ref hasRun, 1) == 0)
        YourCodeToRun();
}
```

Comment: I thought of using count but there are scenarios in which `OnInitializedAsync()` can be called twice. So I need to have the two distinct bools (or ints).

Comment: @DavidThielen you can use `Interlocked.Exchange()` then.

Comment: I looked at `Interlocked.Exchange()` but I didn't see any way to resolve all this with just 2 variables. It's so close that I think maybe there's a way. But that's why I posted because I can't figure it out. What makes this so bloody hard is I can't use a counter across OnInitializedAsync/OnAfterRenderAsync. I have to track each individually completing.

Comment: @DavidThielen then the clearest way would be to use 3 flags.

Comment: First off thank you. Second, is 4 Interlocked calls faster than using lock? [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132209/why-is-interlocked-is-slower-than-lock) it looks like 1 lock == 3 Interlocked calls. But this is 4. For my use it's not called that much (twice per page rendering) so I won't bother benchmarking. But I would definitely benchmark yours vs lock if this code was called a lot. Again, thank you.

Comment: @DavidThielen I would be less concerned about performance, and more worried about race conditions. Multiple individual atomic operations do not equal one combined atomic operation. Funny things could happen in case two threads are doing the `Interlocked` calls in interleaved manner. I am not saying that there is certainly a race condition in this answer. I am saying that it's not trivial to prove that there is not.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I agree with you. Which is an argument for the `lock` approach as that is a single atomic operation. Thanks - very good point.